# Intuition behind the difference between $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ and $\frac{df}{dt}$

Tags: derivatives, soft-question, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

Let $f=f(x,y,t)$. Using the definition of the differential $df$, we can easily conclude that
$\frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + (\vec{v} \cdot \vec{\nabla})f$
$\hspace{2mm} (1)$

So my question is: We refer to both $\frac{df}{dt}$ and
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ as a change of the quantity $f$ with respect to $t$. But what does each time derivative symbolize in eq$(1)$? How could I measure them?

(I know the definition of partial derivative and the role of
$(\vec{v} \cdot \vec{\nabla})f$ in eq$(1)$. All I want is to understand the connection the $2$ derivatives in eq$(1)$.)

Comment: What is $\vec v$?

Comment: @zoli I guess speed?

Comment: Two different functions are both being called by the same name $f$. In my opinion this causes a lot of confusion.

Comment: @littleO There is only one function. $f$

Comment: @MixalisGaitanas What I mean is that the function which is called $f\circ \gamma$ in edm's answer below is simply called "$f$" in the question statement, even though $f\circ \gamma$ is a different function than $f$ (so it deserves to have its own name). This is a common abuse of notation, but I think it consistently causes confusion.

Answer (score 4):

$\partial f/\partial t$ means "I sit at a fixed point $(x,y)$ and change $t$ a bit", i.e. 
$$f(x,y,t+h) = f(x,y,t) + h \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,y,t) + o(h). $$

$df/dt$ means "I'm on a path $(x(t),y(t))$, and look at how $f$ changes as $t$ changes a bit (and I move a bit as well)", i.e.
$$ f(x(t+h),y(t+h),t+h) = f(x(t)+hx'(t)+o(h),y(t)+hy'(t)+o(h),t+h) \\
= f(x(t),y(t),t)+h\left(x'(t) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + y'(t) \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \right)(x(t),y(t),t) + o(h). $$

Answer (score 2):

1. With a function $f(x,y,t)$, the notation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ denotes the change of $f$ with respect to $t$ **while leaving $x$ and $y$ constant**.
2. But if $x$ and $y$ are not held constant, but are themselves dependenat on $t$, we may write $f(x(t),y(t),t)$ and then use differentiation rules to get $\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$

The mathematical formal way to get out of this ambiguity is to always write the parameters as in
$\frac{\partial f(x,y,t)}{\partial t}$
and
$\frac{\partial f(x(t),y(t),t)}{\partial t}$. But thats a lot to write and we are lazy, so we the short-hand notation $d$ and $\partial$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$$ is the variation of $f$ due to time alone, while keeping $x,y$ constant, i.e. staying at a fixed location.

$$\frac{df}{dt}$$ is a total variation due to both the effect of time and of displacement. In particular, it $v$ is the velocity of a particle in motion in a fluid, the total derivative describes the variations seen by that particle as it moves. In this case, it is called the material derivative.

Comment: I thank you for the answer. So if I understand well enough, what you are saying is: Suppose f represents the temperature $(T)$ inside a room, There are $2$ ways to measure a change in $T$. The $1_{st}$ one is to somehow regulate $T$ while I am standing still in the room (that corresponds to the term $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$) and the $2_{nd}$ one is to start moving around the room and since $T$ depends on $x,y$ too, I will also measure changes in $T$ (that corresponds to the term $(\vec{v} \cdot \vec{\nabla})f$. Thanks in advance

Comment: @MixalisGaitanas: exactly. As an illustration, it the temperature remains uniform in the room but changes over time, you only have a $\partial f/\partial t$ term. And if the temperatures remain constant but non uniform, you only have a term $v\nabla f$.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be cleared up in a very formal way, but this may be complicated to understand.

So $f$ is a function of three variable, i.e. $f$ has domain $\Bbb R^3$. The symbol $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ just means partial derivative with respect to the third variable. Nothing special here.

To interpret the symbol $\frac{df}{dt}$, we introduce a function $\gamma:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R^3$, written as $\gamma(t)=(x,y,t)$, which specifies how the variables $x,y$ depends on $t$. Then $\frac{df}{dt}$ should be properly written as $\frac{d(f\circ \gamma)}{dt}$. There should be no ambiguity in how to interpret the last symbol as $f\circ \gamma$ has domain and codomain being $\Bbb R$.

The equality $$\frac{d(f\circ \gamma)}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt} +\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$$ is then a result of chain rule.

Comment: Nice answer. I think it's important to distinguish between the functions $f\circ \gamma$ and $f$, as you have done here. We could also use the notation $\hat f(t) = f(x(t), y(t),t)$.

Answer (score 0):

Regards..Mixalis. 
I may say that the usage of partial derivative $ \frac{\partial f(x,y,t)}{\partial t}$ is *treating* the function $f$ as *multivariable function*. $x$ , $y$, and $z$ are independent variables.

**But**, in some cases, for example in modelling fluids using partial diff. equation, we would like to express the solution $f$ as
$$f(x(t),y(t),t)$$
The functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are called the *characteristic function*. So $\frac{df}{dt}$ acts as a derivation of *one* variable function. You can learn about the simplest PDE that has *characteristic* method for its solution, which is **the advection/translation equation**. In this solution of advection eqn, each particles move along the curve $(x(t),y(t))$. So $(x(t),y(t))$ tracks the movement of particles.

If $f(x,y,t)= x + y + t$, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = 1$.

But, if we would like to see how **$f$ changes in a particular path $(x(t),y(t))$**, the derivative $\frac{d f}{dt} = x'(t) + y'(t) + 1$ is used. This measures the rate of change of $f$ along a particular path/trail $(x(t),y(t))$.

Thanks.